# Hints to deduce convergence of an infinite product to $e^{-x^2}$ on $(0,1)$, and for a numeric series involving number-theoretic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, infinite-product, arithmetic-functions

Exponentiating to get the gaussian $e^{-x^2}$, for $0<x<1$ from the infinite product that satisfies the Möbius function, see the identity (16) from the article [*Möbius Function* from MathWolrd](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html), then I've asked myself

> **Question 1.** Can be proven that the sequence of partial products $$ \left\{ \prod_{k=1}^n  \left( 1-x^k \right)^{\frac{\mu(k)}{k}x} \right\}_{n\geq 1} $$ is uniformly convergent to our gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ on $(0,1)$?  What are your hints?  **Many thanks.**

*I say a proof without* using explicitly the identity that I've evoked as main argument in the proof. I believe that our sequence of partial products is uniformly convergent on compact subsets of $(0,1)$, what I would like to learn is how to formalize this claim, I remember Cauchy condition.

I did a second set of calculations inspired in the fact that $\int e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname{erf}(x)+\operatorname{constant}$.  Combining the Prime Number Theorem with the MacLaurin series expansion of the Error function $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ defined from this [MathWorld article for *Erf*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) (the examples seems also feasibles for $\operatorname{erfi}(z)$ ). Combining also with a related Dirichlet series. Then walking this way I can deduce identities whose series in my RHS have terms involving particular values of the Riemann Zeta function, for example for $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda(k)\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the Liouville function. I would like to know some rigurous proof or reasoning to convice us that previous series is convergent. I believe that the series in our LHS for each of our examples, doesn't converge absolutely.

> **Question 2.** Please, what is your explanation or hints to show that  $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda(k)\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ does converge? **Thanks and good wishes.**

*My reasoning to get a different example.* Since the example seems also feasible with the Möbius function instead Liouville function, and same error function, my justification for this different example was using the ratio test in RHS $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}   \right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)(2n+1)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\zeta(2n+1)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\zeta(2n+1)}=0\cdot1\cdot1=0<1,$$ and thus our series converges, but as I am saying I would like to know your calculations and reasonings for previous different example in Question 2, to do a comparison.

Comment: Take the log of the product to make it a sum ;)  Take the Taylor expansion of the log if the previous was too hard.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and hints @SimpleArt

Comment: Is your first sentence a sentence?  Also, what is $\mu(k)$?

Comment: @Michael Appears to be the mobius function by the link he gave.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @Michael the exponentiantion by $x$ of (16) of this [Mathwolrd aticle for Möbius function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html) provide us $e^{-x^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider $$f\left(x\right)=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\mu\left(k\right)}{k}\log\left(1-x^{k}\right).
 $$ Now for the [Möbius inversion for the power series](http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/actas-sjtn2007-BenitoNavasVarona.pdf) we get $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{f\left(x^{k}\right)}{k}=-\log\left(1-x\right)
 $$ hence $f\left(x\right)=x
 $ and so $$\prod_{k\geq1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{x\mu\left(k\right)/k}=\exp\left(x\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\mu\left(k\right)}{k}\log\left(1-x^{k}\right)\right)=\exp\left(-x^{2}\right).
 $$ For the second we may use $$\textrm{erf}\left(x\right)\sim\frac{2x}{\sqrt{\pi}},\, x\rightarrow0
 $$ hence $$\lambda\left(k\right)\textrm{erf}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\sim\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\lambda\left(k\right)}{k}
 $$ and recalling that $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\lambda\left(k\right)}{k^{s}}=\frac{\zeta\left(2s\right)}{\zeta\left(s\right)}$$ we can conclude.

Comment: Many thanks, I will study in next hours your answer.

Comment: I understand now better the convergence of the infnite product. Thanks one more time.